# How to get specific child from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get specific child from db.
Here my db :

[image: ss]

I want to get random of this ones.
For example i want to get 3. child how can I get it directly ?

Comment: The Firebase documentation has a pretty good section on reading lists of data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events Did you try anything like that yet? If so, can you show where you got stuck?

Comment: I know how to get query of childs but i mean i need get just one specific child.

Comment: That'd be: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events If you show us what you've already tried, it is much more likely that someone can help.

Comment: No it's not. I mean imagine you had 231 children and you want to get 123. one how can you get it directly without get all childs ?